# MySQL sub-query only returns result on top row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I can't work out how to do something that I'm sure is pretty simple. I have the following code:

```
SELECT SA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
,SA.BALANCE
,`TOT`.TOTAL_BALANCE
,(SA.BALANCE/`TOT`.TOTAL_BALANCE)*100 AS PERCENT_OVER_FSCS_LIMIT

FROM savingsaccount SA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
,ENCODEDKEY
FROM
savingsaccount
 ) AS `TOT` ON TOT.ENCODEDKEY= SA.ENCODEDKEY


where accountstate = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY SA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
```

As you can see, I'm trying to work out how much of a % the balance of each ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY is against the total of all balances. The sub query to get the total of all balances doesn't work however, as it only returns a number on the top row. I assume my error is somewhere in the join logic?

Comment: Your sub query is bringing back a 'random' value of ENCODEDKEY to go with the sum, then you use that for the JOIN. Remove ENCODEDKEY from the sub query SELECT, remove the ON clause of the JOIN and use a CROSS JOIN rather than a LEFT OUTER JOIN (as there should always be a record there this should be fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cross join:-

```
SELECT SA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
        ,SA.BALANCE
        ,`TOT`.TOTAL_BALANCE
        ,(SA.BALANCE/`TOT`.TOTAL_BALANCE)*100 AS PERCENT_OVER_FSCS_LIMIT
FROM savingsaccount SA
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
    FROM savingsaccount
) AS `TOT`
WHERE accountstate = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY SA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
```

As if you have any row coming back from the main query there will always be a row from the sub query then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

*Sigh*

So I really was having a complete brain fart. I need more sleep!

The answer to my query was just to include the subquery in the select statement:

```
SELECT SA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
,(SELECT
sum(balance)
from
savingsaccount
WHERE
ACCOUNTSTATE = 'ACTIVE') AS TOTAL_DEPOSIT_BALANCE

FROM savingsaccount SA

where accountstate = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY SA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
```